# How to nest php inside if statement

Tags: php

Probably a newbie thing but I can't get the meta name="description" row to work. You should close and open PHP-code if its nested, right?

Thanks!
/Robert

```
<?php 
    $blogname = get_bloginfo('name');
    if ($blogname == 'Wobbling Willy') {
        echo '<meta name="description" content="?><?php bloginfo('description'); ?><?php" />'."\n";
        echo '<meta name="keywords" content=”keyword1, keyword2, keyword3” />'."\n";
    }
?>
```

Comment: try to print_r($blogname) and check what is coming and how the format is

Comment: You dont need to leave php to nest php `echo "<htmltag>Mytext{$variablefromphp}</htmltag>";`

Comment: `echo '<meta name="description" content="'. bloginfo('description') .'"/>'."\n";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like this syntax myself ( when working in mixed HTML/PHP )

```
<?php 
    $blogname = get_bloginfo('name');
    if ($blogname == 'Wobbling Willy'):  //-note- colon not semi-colon
?>
<meta name="description" content="<?= bloginfo('description'); ?>" />
<meta name="keywords" content=”keyword1, keyword2, keyword3” />
<?php endif; ?>
```

OR

```
<?php 
    $blogname = get_bloginfo('name');
    if ($blogname == 'Wobbling Willy'){  //open bracket
?>
<meta name="description" content="<?= bloginfo('description'); ?>" />
<meta name="keywords" content=”keyword1, keyword2, keyword3” />
<?php } // close bracket?>
```

It's shorter and you don't have to worry about quoting.  Or even use a heredoc
but that involves setting `bloginfo('description')` to a variable and a few other quirks...

```
<?php 
    $blogname = get_bloginfo('name');
    if ($blogname == 'Wobbling Willy'){  //open bracket
        $description = bloginfo('description');
        echo <<<HTML
            <meta name="description" content="$description" />
            <meta name="keywords" content=”keyword1, keyword2, keyword3” />
HTML; //nothing can go here no space ( before or after ) and not even this comment, nothing but HTML; litterally
    } 
?>
```

HEREDOC is my preferred way, but I never mix HTML and PHP in the same file.  Because I use a template system.

Comment: Wow this was fast answers!
This one
echo '<meta name="description" content="'. bloginfo('description') .'"/>'."\n";
output
Wobbling Willy<meta name="description" content="" />

Comment: ArtisticPhoenix solution works.
Is that a colon at end of if row?

Thanks!

Comment: yes, its `:` and not ';` its a alternative PHP syntax, often overlooked.  But I like it.  You can split the brackets too like this  `<?php if( .. ){ ?> HTML <?php }?>`

Comment: Okay got it, its instead of curly brackets.

Comment: yes, you can do same with `foreach( ):  endforeach;`  etc...  I like it because its easier to read, ie. what this is `}` if you have nesting whats this `}}` easier `endif; endforeach;`

Comment: HEREDOC is another way to do a string or a text block, using a normal string and HTML is probably my least preferred way, because it can make quoting difficult if you have Javascript in there ( for example )

Comment: Thanks everybody! I'm a first comer here and this was really a 100% positive experience. Why didn't I post my own questions before...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php 
    $blogname = get_bloginfo('name');
    if ($blogname == 'Wobbling Willy') {
        echo '<meta name="description" content="'.bloginfo('description').'"/>\n';
        echo '<meta name="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2, keyword3"/>\n';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In reply to the OP's question about nested PHP tags, the nesting of PHP opening and closing tags only applies to doing so *within HTML code*, as follows:

```
<div id="<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

Note: this style of mixing HTML and PHP together was far more popular years ago; nowadays this is not considered the best style. Instead, the emphasis is on a separation of concerns, as reflected in the model-view-controller design pattern.  And, nesting PHP code within PHP is not the thing to do and will likely produce a parse error.

Of the various ways to fix the code, you may wish to view my [live demo](https://3v4l.org/I2jgc#outputt) which makes use of [*heredoc*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax.

What is interesting about the OP's snippet is that it actually does not have any PHP tags nested within PHP code. In fact, if you remove the superfluous tags, allowing for only one open tag, the code just needs minor tweaking to work, as follows:

```
// these function implementations are just for demo purposes:
function get_bloginfo($n) {
   return ("Wobbling Willy");
}
function bloginfo($d){
   return("some lovely description ...");
}

$blogname = get_bloginfo('name');
if ($blogname == 'Wobbling Willy') {
    echo '<meta name="description" content="';
    echo bloginfo('description'),'"/>',"\n"; 
    echo '<meta name="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2, keyword3" />'."\n";
}
```

See [demo](https://3v4l.org/NlrGI#output)

The return value of bloginfo() will not appear unless provided as a  parameter to a function or construct, such as **echo**, which will output it. Splitting up the  display of the "description" meta tag while awkward will work provided that one uses the single quotes as needed. Lastly, curly quotes can be problematic and in this case I replaced those enveloping the second meta tag's content with straight ones to enclose the keywords.